# Ubuntu 12.04 won't install

Tags: installation

I have a problem I have had before. When I create a USB drive to install Ubuntu 12.04 using startup disk creator, it won't work. It doesn't give me any errors, but when I restart the PC to boot into the USB drive (settings are correct in BIOS), I get the option to:
1) Try Live CD
2) Install Ubuntu 12.04
3) Check the disk

I choose option 2 and after that, nothing happens, just black screen no matter how long I wait.

I tried creating the USB using unetbootin, on both Ubuntu 11.10 and Windows 7, but same issue.

I have had this problem installing Ubuntu 11.10 too, but it was solved by creating the USB drive in Linux Mint. But I don't have Mint installed now, so I hope someone knows what the problem could be. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this same thing happen when you choose option one? Try live cd. If not, install using this method.

Comment: Option one causes the screen to stay black too, similar to option 2

Comment: You could try re-downlaoding the .iso, it might not have downloaded correctly?

Comment: Ok, so today I redownloaded the iso file, and for a change, I burned it on a CD. Same thing, so blank screen. But I noticed the screen goes blank, but the monitor doesn't go in stand-by mode. The CD-drive kept reading the CD, so maybe it's doing what it is supposed to do, but there's just no output to the screen, so maybe a graphics driver issue? Is there a command I can pass along the installation?

Comment: I'm sorry I do not know a command for you, maybe someone else could help? But in the mean time I would suggest taking your graphics card out if you have one and try installing then, If you don't have one try putting one in!

Comment: If this doesn't help you could try changing some of the parameters (bottom right of the screen?) and see if that helps, I had a problem like this ages ago and changing those helped, I just messed around changing different ones to see if it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed the problem myself.

I got a tip to use the Ubuntu Alternate CD, so I burned that one, giving me another installation interface, which installed perfectly, but after rebooting it got stuck on a purple screen.

I went back to the Ubuntu 12.04 64bit USB-stick, and added a parameter to the installation, namely "nomodeset", which is a work around for people with GFX card which is not open-sourced supported by Ubuntu. Installation went fine, everything works as it should, and added the propietary drivers later.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like YUMI to put the image on the drive, I've seen similar problems from unetbootin before.

Comment: I tried both YUMI and Universal USB installer, both the same problem exists, so I am starting to think it has a different cause. Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would like you to use [Universal USB installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) and create a bootable USB from there. I had my Ubuntu 12.04 installed from that tool without any hassle

Answer (score 0):

the blank screen showed in mine. It works as you would observe the CD reading as ubuntu is being installed. Increase the display light on your screen and you would see everything clearly. Ubuntu has a way of dimming the lights to the minimum when running on windows and don't know why it happens